# Find strings with round brackets

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regex to find all words matching following pattern:

- contains passed word - e.g "most_popular"
- has round brackets right after it
- selects it with all content inside the brackets

Example:

```
most_popular(z,y)

most_popular

most_popular ()

most_popular(z,x)
```

Should select only:

```
most_popular(z,y)

most_popular(z,x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking "most_popular" as key word. How about:

```
most_popular\(.*?\)
```

This Returns your key word plus the brackets and everything inside.